# Flutter How can I build my own scroll physics in this framework?

Tags: flutter, dart, physics

I want to build my own custom scroll physic. I've followed along with a tutorial to learn how I can do this. But I do not understand how this physics and simulation structure works in Flutter. Unfortunately there are not many tutorials or documentations on this topic. Can you give me an explanation of how the physics and simulations work in Flutter. How can I detect swipes ? Are the finals in the "MySimulation" Class defined by Flutter ? Which can I use ? Do I have to write it this or could I use other ways ?

How could I make my own ScrollPhysics in my written framework ?

Thank you for your help

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math' as math;




class MySimulation extends Simulation {
  final double initPosition;
  final double velocity;

  MySimulation({this.initPosition, this.velocity});

  @override
  double x(double time) {
    return initPosition;
  }

  @override
  double dx(double time) {
    return velocity;
  }

  @override
  bool isDone(double time) {
    return false;
  }
}

class MyScrollPhysics extends ScrollPhysics {
  @override
  ScrollPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    return MyScrollPhysics();
  }

  @override
  Simulation createClampingScrollSimulation(
      ScrollMetrics position, double velocity) {
    return MySimulation(
      initPosition: 0,
      velocity: 0,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this question is a bit too broad to be a good fit for stackoverflow, and you're asking a bunch of different questions. Generally the best questions ask "how can I solve X problem" not "how do I do X" - as there are a variety of approaches that could work here.

That being said, I think you're looking for a combination of ScrollController, GestureDetector, and the ScrollPhysics you've already found. ScrollPhysics in flutter are more to control what happens after a user flicks a scrollable widget, whereas it sounds like you're trying to change how the flicking part is done.

Comment: A better example of a question would be "How can I increase scroll resistance in flutter so that scrolling is damped by half" as that is an approachable problem that someone could tackle. Breaking down the question into parts like that is much more likely to get you useful answers.